# How can I convert images saved as ascii to binary?

Tags: php, ftp, binary, ascii

i used [ftp-get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) function to download images from server. But by accident i used FTP_ASCII mode, so i have a problem. Images couldn't be read, there is some error.

I have no option to download images again.
Anyone knows how to convert these files into binary form, or how to repair these files?

Comment: Oh dear. I am quite sure there is some way but I don't have an answer - don't give up yet though!

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/195612/recovering-corrupted-files-uploaded-in-wrong-ftp-mode

Comment: What file type were the images and what OS did you download them to?

Comment: @deed02392 that was jpg files. I downloaded them from some linux OS to server with CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way to repair the files because of the nature of the way ASCII mode works compared to Binary mode.

FTP ASCII mode is designed to convert line endings to the appropriate type between the source and destination operating systems. The most common conversion that is done here is `\n` (`0x0a`) becomes `\r\n` (`0x0d0a`) and vice versa, when transferring between *nix and Windows.

Lets say that we are transferring some images from a Linux server to a Windows machine, and we accidentally use ASCII mode. The FTP client is looking out for any `\n` sequences in the incoming data and converting them to `\r\n` in the data it saves to disk. This means that anywhere in the binary data there is a `0x0a` it becomes `0x0d0a` in the new data. But it *won't* convert an existing `\r\n` to `\r\r\n` - this will be left intact. No problem, you might think, I'll just convert all the `0x0d0a` back to `0x0a` and the file will be repaired. But wait... if the existing `\r\n` sequences weren't converted, then they will be converted the wrong way in this new conversion pass.

The long of the short of it is you data is irrevocably corrupted. The only 100% guaranteed way to get the correct data back is to copy them off the server again, in binary mode.

Comment: This is how the linked superuser solution works - bruteforcing reassemblies of the data based on instances of 0x0d0a and testing it is valid. This user should try and obtain that source but implement a way to test if the image is made valid with his combination of fixes of the ASCII data.

Comment: Transfer was from linux to linux os, so there shouldn't be any problems with this.

But still I don't know how to do conversion. I tried some php functions, but images stil don't work. Can you suggest something?


PS. I can't download files again.

Comment: If it was from linux to linux, the corruption has occured because every occurence of `0x0d` has been converted to `0x0a`. However, it is unlikely that *all* the `0x0a`s in your corrupted file should be `0x0d`, the only way to repair the file would be to brute force it. This is not a simple task and there is no easy way to do it... I take it that there is no way that you can get the original data from the original server? How many/how big files are we talking about here?

Comment: Yes, i can't get the original data from server. It was something about 60GB of files, i can't remember how many, but a lot, thousands. I have copies on HDDs and CDs, but I hoped that there is some easy way to convert files...

Comment: The only thing you could do would be to brute-force it, which with that quantity of data could take years, and is still not guaranteed. Essentially what any program would have to do is search through the entire file, and look for any `0x0a` byte, and try replacing it with `0x0d` or `0x0d0a` or leaving it alone and validate the file. You would have to try (potentially) every possible combination in every possible file, which for a large file is potentially millions of combinations. Then you would have to validate the image, and the only real way to do that is to manually open and inspect.

Comment: In short, unfortunately, there is nothing that anyone can really do for you or you can do for yourself. Sorry.

Comment: So the easiest way to repair galleries would be copy images from HDDs.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, the data is corrupted and potentially unrecoverable.

However, 0x0D 0x0A isn't a particularly common sequence of bytes in most binary file formats [citation needed!], so it's worth a try replacing them to see if that fixes the file.

The [fixgz utility](http://www.gzip.org/#faq1) does just that. Despite it's name, it has nothing specific to .gzip files and can be used on any file.

Good luck!